# How to set immutable data derived from prop which may change

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to complete a demo which is similar to Todo-List,and the drawing is [image]

**Parent.vue**

```
<template>
<li v-show="currentTab === 1">
    <child key="1" :items="projects"></child>
</li>
<li v-show="currentTab === 2">
    <child key="2" :items="awards"></child>
</li>
</template>
<script>
export default {

data: function() {
    return {
        awards: [{
            name: ''
        }],
        projects:[{
            content:''
        }]
    }
},
}

</script>
```

**Child.vue**

```
<template>
<div>
    <el-form>
        <div v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="index">
            <el-form-item>
                <el-input v-model="item[key]"></el-input>
            </el-form-item>
            <i class="el-icon-close" @click="remove(index)"></i>
        </div>
        <el-button type="primary" @click="add">Add</el-button>
    </el-form>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
props: ['items'],
computed: {
    keys: function() {
        return Object.keys(this.items[0])
    },
},
// data: function() {
//     return {
//         copyItems: this.items.slice(0)
//     }
// },
methods: {
    add: function() {
        let temp = {}
        this.keys.map((key) => {
            temp[key] = ''
        })
        this.items.push(temp)
    },
    remove: function(index) {
        this.items.splice(index, 1)
    }
}
}
</script>
```

and the problem is when the method **remove** invoked then the **items** is **[]**,the computed property **keys** will get error ,the reason is **this.items[0]** doesn't exist,and the method **add**  is unavailable, Maybe I should define another prop to get key derived form Parent.vue like this:

`<child key="1" :items="projects" objectKey="content"></child>
<child key="2" :items="awards" objectKey="name"></child>`

while I think this way  is not appropriate. so how to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When deleting, if there is only one item in the list, don't delete it, just initialize it to empty. The list will never be empty and you will always have keys.

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: '#child-template',
  props: ['items'],
  computed: {
    keys: function() {
      return Object.keys(this.items[0]);
    },
  },
  methods: {
    initialize: function (item) {
      this.keys.map((key) => {
        item[key] = '';
      });
    },
    add: function() {
      let temp = {}
      this.initialize(temp);
      this.items.push(temp)
    },
    remove: function(index) {
      if (this.items.length > 1) {
        this.items.splice(index, 1)
      }
      else {
        this.initialize(this.items[0]);
      }
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      currentTab: 1,
      awards: [{
        name: ''
      }],
      projects: [{
        content: ''
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <li v-show="currentTab === 1">
    <child key="1" :items="projects"></child>
  </li>
  <li v-show="currentTab === 2">
    <child key="2" :items="awards"></child>
  </li>
  <div v-for="item in projects">{{item.content}}</div>
</div>

<template id="child-template">
<div>
    <el-form>
        <div v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="index">
            <div>
                <input v-model="item[keys[0]]">
            </div>
            <button class="el-icon-close" @click="remove(index)">X</button>
        </div>
        <button type="primary" @click="add">Add</button>
    </el-form>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: if keys is [],the method **add** is unavailable,then I can't push new object into items('cause there is no key).that's why i am wondering whether I should define another prop to get the key(such as "name")

Comment: er,surely it will add,but when I click the **add** button,  input some value and console.log(this.items),I find that the key  is "0","1"...I want **this.items** to be like  [{name:"foo"},{name:"bar"}]

Comment: I'm sorry I did't describe the question clearly.In **Parent.vue**,pass different value(projects,awards) to component **Child**,so I can't put "name" or "content" as the default value,there is only **one** Child.vue

Comment: Se newly-updated answer. Note that it includes a fix to the `v-model` parameter.